How to leverage SSR in a shared hosting plan
I want to dynamically change meta tags on my SPA, but of course that was a challenge, react helmet works well, but crawlers only see the first loaded index.html before in JS, which results in an SEO stroke as google now thinks I have 246 duplicate pages lol.
Tried React-helmet, it does change the meta tags but of course since it's rendering client side, crawlers wouldnt be able to get the updated meta tags, so it just parses the original index.html meta tags
